# Database Schema for Itinerary

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema

How would you go about design a database schema for a travel agent that has to store trip itineraries?

TRIPS have many ITEMS (type: Bus, Hire Car, Hotel, Flight, etc)

My problem is that in some instances items may have sub items (such as flight segments) that have the same 'reservation number', etc.

My current solution is to store the item (and its subitems) metadata using the PostgreSQL JSON data type. Is this the best possible way? It just feels like I'm cramming all the useful information into a schemaless form.

[image: Query]

This problem must have been fixed many times before by the likes of tripit, expedia or just your local travel agent - I just haven't been able to find any documentation/references. Thoughts?

Comment: this looks like a simple relational decomposition problem - i.e. normalisation. If there's no natural key, use a synthetic key.

Comment: i want to make same solution, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a table for each conceptually different "thing" you are trying to describe. Don't bother grouping everything under an "ITEM" category, as I don't see why that would do anything but complicate the problem.

I definitely would not just do a whole bunch of JSON data in a column like that for this problem. Do it all with a standard, normalized relational database.

- A `TRIP` has one `CLIENT`, and a `CLIENT` has zero to many `TRIP`s
- A `TRIP` has zero to many `FLIGHT`s, and a `FLIGHT` has one `TRIP`
- Each `FLIGHT` has a `RESERVATION_NUMBER` attribute
- A `FLIGHT` has one to many `LEG`s, and a `LEG` has one `FLIGHT`
- Each `LEG` has `START` and `END` attributes

Hopefully you get the idea here so that you can apply the concept to the other types of things you want to record about a trip (bus, car, hotel, etc.).